# Average Value of $f(x,y)= \sqrt{4+9y^{2/3}} $on the curve $y=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: calculus

I would like to find the average value of $f(x,y)= \sqrt{4+9y^{2/3}}$ on the curve $y=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$, for $0\le x \le 5$.

I am not sure how to go about this question.
I tried plugging in $y$ into the function and derive it from there but I did not get the right answer. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of a physical analogy, you have a wire that you lay down along $y=x^{3/2}$, with $0\le x\le5$, and you know the linear density of the wire at every point on this curve $f(x,y)=\sqrt{4+9y^{2/3}}$. The length of the wire is $$L=\int_{curve}dl=\int_0^5dx\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}=\int_0^5dx\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3 x^{1/2}}{2}\right)^2}=\int_0^5dx\sqrt{1+\frac{9x}{4}}$$
The total mass of the wire is given by $$M=\int_{curve}dl f(l)=\int_0^5dx\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}f(x,y)=\int_0^5dx\sqrt{1+\frac{9x}{4}}\sqrt{4+9\left(x^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}}$$
I will let you figure out these integrals. the answer should be $M/L$